# Beautiful Soup 4 UnicodeEncodeError When Using get_text()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the text from a web page, following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/). However I can not seem to get all the text from the web page using get_text(), instead I get the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1d90' in
>   position 2473: character maps to

Here is what my source code looks like:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?. I have followed several other answers on Stack Overflow and tried:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml').encode('UTF-8')
```

but get the error:

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Just tested myself and it actually worked on V3.5.1

Comment: I did a bit more research and [according to this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4tvrld/more_unicode_frustration/) it might be a command prompt issue. What are you using to run the script if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Just used the terminal. Also did a quick test in jupiter notebook. Both was running without error.